# How to get the selected checkbox values in gwt?

Tags: gwt

I have form panel in which there are 20 check boxes i want to get the list of all selected check boxes on form submit.Could some one show some code sample or tell how i should do it?

```
<g:FormPanel ui:field="form">
    <g:FlowPanel ui:field="flowPanel" width="580px" height="364px">
    <g:HorizontalPanel width="460px" height="48px">
        <g:Label height="33px">FC NAME:</g:Label>
        <g:TextBox height="23px" ui:field="fcname"></g:TextBox>
        <g:Button ui:field="button1">Button 1</g:Button>
        <g:Button ui:field="button2">Button 2</g:Button>
    </g:HorizontalPanel>
    <g:Label>FCP Values</g:Label>
    <g:VerticalPanel ui:field="verticalPanel">
        <g:CheckBox ui:field="cb1" formValue="value 1">value 1</g:CheckBox>
        <g:CheckBox ui:field="cb2" formValue="value 2">value 2</g:CheckBox>
        <g:CheckBox ui:field="cb3" formValue="value 3">value 3</g:CheckBox>
        <g:CheckBox ui:field="cb4" formValue="value 4">value 4</g:CheckBox>
        <g:CheckBox ui:field="cb5" formValue="value 5">value 5</g:CheckBox>
        <g:CheckBox ui:field="cb6" formValue="value 6">value 6</g:CheckBox>
    </g:VerticalPanel>
    <g:Button ui:field="submit">Submit</g:Button>
    </g:FlowPanel>
</g:FormPanel>
</g:DecoratorPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: Show some example code of your own so we can see how the panel is structured and how your submit is implemented etc.

Answer (score 0):

First solution: declare all the checkboxs in the view and read all of them when the submit event occurs.

Second solution: browser all the `verticalPanel` children casting them to CheckBox when the submit event occurs.